# Https PUT request with user name and password which send the JSON file as a payload

Tags: java, json, http, httprequest

I am new to java. I have a URL, UserName, Password. I need to make a PUT HTTP request using the URL, UserName and Password.
I have to send JSON file as a payload using the HTTP Put request to the system which can accept only JSON.

I have searched in StackOverFlow and found few suggestions which can make a simple request to the URL without User name and Password. But our URL need to be authenticated to make a request.

Code which i have used to make a HTTP request

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
 {
  String userPassword = "";
  String encoding = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes()));
  URL url = new URL(URL);
  HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
  httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
  httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoding);
  OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
  out.write("Resource content");
  out.close();
  httpCon.getInputStream();
 }
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? What isn't working, the authentication? Do you get error messages?

Comment: I am getting the following error
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

Comment: I need java code which helps me in making the HTTP request and possibly helps me in sending the JSON data to the URL through Http request.

Answer (score 0):

use volley library..its easy

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "<your url>";

    JSONObject jsonrequest=new JSONObject();
    jsonrequest.put("username",<username>);
    jsonrequest.put("password",<password>);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonrequest, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //your code to handle when response came
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: could you please help me in downloading the  volley  libraries ?

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Comment: Android Studio or Eclipse?